# Can't do a multiple line plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataset with a column of unemployment, a column of months, and one for years.

I want to do a line plot where I have month number on the x axis, unemployment on the y axis and that each line represents a different year.

I first filtered the dataframe by year to have the y values for each year individually and I tried the following code:

```
y1 = df %>% filter(year == 1996) 
y1 = y1$unemploy
y2 = df %>% filter(year == 1997)
y2 = y2$unemploy
y3 = df %>% filter(year == 1998)
y3 = y3$unemploy 

plot1 = ggplot() +  
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = df$month, y = y1), color = "navyblue") +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = df$month,y = y2), color = "black") +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = df$month,y = y3), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,15)) 
plot1
```

But when I try to print the plot, I get the following error message:

```
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (128): y
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem with this plot?

The output of `dput(head(df,20))` is the following:

```
dput(head(df, 20))
structure(list(unemploy = c(6.7, 6.7, 6.4, 5.9, 5.2, 4.8, 4.8, 
4, 4.2, 4.4, 5, 5, 6.4, 6.5, 6.3, 5.9, 4.9, 4.8, 4.5, 4), month = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), year = c(1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1997L, 1997L, 
1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I think the error is obvious just by looking at the code. OP uses df for month (x) while using a subset of the data for unemploy (y). Did I get that wrong? If so, I am with you on getting a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have edited the question to include the output of the `dput()` function.

Answer (score 2):

For the method you are using, you need to use a different dataset for each geom; you assign all the rows for variable `month` in your df to `x` and only a subset of the unemploy column to `y`, hence, different number of x and y entities in ggplot returns an error.

```
y1 = df %>% filter(year == 1996) 

y2 = df %>% filter(year == 1997)

y3 = df %>% filter(year == 1998)


plot1 = ggplot() +  
  geom_line(y1, aes(x = month, y = unemploy), color = "navyblue") +
  geom_line(y2, aes(x = month, y = unemploy), color = "black") +
  geom_line(y3, aes(x = month, y = unemploy), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,15)) 
plot1
```

But better practice is using `color` within mapping:

```
df %>%
  filter(year %in% c("1996", "1997", "1998")) %>%
ggplot() +  
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = unemploy, color = year)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,15))
```

You can use `scale_color_manual` later, if you want those specific colors and don't like the default ggplot colors.

Comment: Your `filter` piped to `ggplot` would be my 1st choice too, upvote. Since this means that package `dplyr` is loaded, I would also `mutate(year = factor(year))` after filtering the data.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than filtering by year and including three separate `geom_line()`s, just pass the full dataframe to `ggplot()` and map `year` to the `color` and `group` aesthetics. You can specify your colors using `scale_color_manual()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(month, unemploy, color = year, group = year)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("navyblue", "black", "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, .1),
    label = percent
  ) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

*Example data:*

```
set.seed(13)
df <- expand.grid(month = factor(1:12), year = factor(1996:1998))
unemploy <- vector("double", 36)
unemploy[[1]] <- .05
for (i in 2:36) {
  unemploy[[i]] <- unemploy[[i - 1]] + rnorm(1, 0, .005)
}
df$unemploy <- unemploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Not assuming the years are only for years 1996 to 1998, first keep only those years, coerce them to factor and set the aesthetics in the initial call to `ggplot`. The aesthetic `color` will take care of the lines grouping.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

df %>%
  filter(year %in% 1996:1998) %>%
  mutate(year = factor(year)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = unemploy, color = year)) +  
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("navyblue", "black", "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 12), breaks = 1:12) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Unemployment") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data creation code

The data creation code is borrowed from [zephryl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74426846/8245406) with a few changes:

- The years are extended so to have later `filter` actually keep only the years in the question;
- `month` and `factor` are numeric, not factors;
- there is no need for a `for` loop, `unemploy` is created with `cumsum` and its values are consistent with the y axis limits;
- there is no need to create an extra variable, `unemploy`, and then assign it to the data.frame.

```r
set.seed(13)
df <- expand.grid(month = 1:12, year = 1995:1999)
df$unemploy <- 8 + cumsum(rnorm(nrow(df), sd = 0.25))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>